# Flask webapp uploading photo from mobile image gallery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage, camera-roll

I have a Flask app that user can upload photo to Google Cloud Storage. This process works fine on PC also on mobile when choosing to take photo but when uploading from mobile image gallery, the file is not uploaded. Please help.

```
class Image(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)

class ImageForm(FlaskForm):
    photo = FileField('Add Main Photo', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg'])])
    submit = SubmitField('confirm')

def save_picture(form_picture,name):
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], name)
    output_size = (1000,1000)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(app.config['BUCKET'])
    blob = bucket.blob(name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(picture_path)
    return picture_path

@app.route('/testupload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testupload():
    form = ImageForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = 'ID'+uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]
        filename = secure_filename(name+'.jpg')
        try:
            save_picture(form.photo.data, filename)
            db.session.add(Image(location=filename))
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('post'))
        except:
            flash("unsuccess")
            return redirect(url_for('testupload'))
    else:
        return render_template("home.html")
```

HTML File

```
{% extends"layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <div>
    {{ form.photo }}
    {{ form.submit }}
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

This is the log:

2001:44c8:414e:90d5:e88c:6707:ae22:ba7f - - [30/Nov/2019:11:20:22 +0700] "POST /merchant/product HTTP/1.1" 200 3595 http://onedaystory.co/merchant/product "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_4_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "onedaystory.co" ms=176 cpu_ms=66 cpm_usd=4.01772e-7 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117cca6752114064486c70db1c3a067b99d2572773a7df9823648617d70ed3a884ba app_engine_release=1.9.71 trace_id=e873978d627836a53b005b9cc3f2067e

```
{
 httpRequest: {
  status: 200   
 }
 insertId: "5de1ee060003f11d3a306ad9"  
 labels: {
  clone_id: "00c61b117cca6752114064486c70db1c3a067b99d2572773a7df9823648617d70ed3a884ba"   
 }
 logName: "projects/myproject-535/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"  
 operation: {
  first: true   
  id: "5de1ee0600ff013f532e7d0e5800016e7e6d7970726f6a6563742d3533350001323031393131323974313434393033000100"   
  last: true   
  producer: "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id"   
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"   
  appEngineRelease: "1.9.71"   
  appId: "n~myproject-535"   
  cost: 4.01772e-7   
  endTime: "2019-11-30T04:20:22.258180Z"   
  finished: true   
  first: true   
  host: "onedaystory.co"   
  httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"   
  instanceId: "00c61b117cca6752114064486c70db1c3a067b99d2572773a7df9823648617d70ed3a884ba"   
  instanceIndex: -1   
  ip: "2001:44c8:414e:90d5:e88c:6707:ae22:ba7f"   
  latency: "0.176433s"   
  megaCycles: "66"   
  method: "POST"   
  referrer: "http://onedaystory.co/merchant/product"   
  requestId: "5de1ee0600ff013f532e7d0e5800016e7e6d7970726f6a6563742d3533350001323031393131323974313434393033000100"   
  resource: "/merchant/product"   
  responseSize: "3595"   
  startTime: "2019-11-30T04:20:22.081747Z"   
  status: 200   
  traceId: "e873978d627836a53b005b9cc3f2067e"   
  traceSampled: true   
  urlMapEntry: "auto"   
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_4_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"   
  versionId: "20191129t144903"   
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-30T04:20:22.271160187Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id: "default"    
   project_id: "myproject-535"    
   version_id: "20191129t144903"    
   zone: "asia-east2-2"    
  }
  type: "gae_app"   
 }
 timestamp: "2019-11-30T04:20:22.081747Z"  
 trace: "projects/myproject-535/traces/e873978d627836a53b005b9cc3f2067e"  
 traceSampled: true  
}
```

Comment: You need to describe a bit what "uploading from camera roll" means (I'm old enough for it to mean something else for me) as well as give more info about the "the file is not uploaded" (errors, logs, etc) portion.

Comment: I mean the photo storage on your mobile when you capture a photo using your phone. The issue is when click form.photo button, it allows you to browse file, choose from photo gallery or take a photo. If you take a photo. the image is uploaded successfully but if you choose to select from photo gallery, the image will not be uploaded. In my case, it just flashes 'unsuccess'.

Comment: hey @pie, can you please provide more information so I can help you? like: check your Google Cloud Platform [Loggings](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) and provide with logs related to this issue. Also, check your [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors) and provide me with tracebacks if exisit. after that, I will gladly help you.

Comment: thanks @MethkalKhalawi i have updated the log. There is no Error Report.

Comment: The request log you added was made to the `/merchant/product` path, not to the `/testupload` path. Either it's not the right request log or the request isn't actually made to the right path, which could explain why there is no upload.